# Deciphering Thin Copper and Fabric Wires in Cable

Tags: wire, cables, insulation

I'm planning on connecting a Nintendo Wii Classic controller directly to IC2 input on a RP2 board.

The controller I'd like to use is a Black Wii Classic Controller.

Here's some photos of the Controller cable. I need to figure out which of the smaller cables will need to be connected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJjdj.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q104a.jpg

Which of the above cables will need to be utilized? I'm not sure what the thin (copper?) wires surrounding the coloured cables are for, or the central copper wire. My guess is it's a ground connection and the thin wires are for protection.  Also not sure about the fabric wire (it's either nylon or polyester).

I'll probably have to open up the controller to see what the Red, White, Yellow, and Green cable control. I don't have the controller in front of me ATM but I don't recall if it has screws on the body so I'll have to try to pry it open carefully.

If anyone can give me a hand in identifying these wires that would be a big help.When I connect the colored cables can I just cut off the thin copper wires? What about the central copper wire and the fabric?

Comment: https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/videogame/nintendo-wiimote/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fine copper wires are the shield which is spirally wrapped around the inner conductors.  The pinout reference posted by @pjc50 says that the outer shield is not connected. So that apparently means you can cut the wires off.

The white fibrous stuff is not conductive. It is partly for physical strength, and partly to fill in the space so that the overall profile of the wire is nice and round.  Just cut it off completely. Of course be very careful not to cut any of the wires. This is not referring to the actual wire with a white insulation.

Comment: That pinout table says there are two red cables. I only have one red cable. But there was also a thick copper wire around the same diameter as the colored cables.

Comment: There is no "thick copper wire around the same diameter as the colored cables" shown in your photos???  I would assume that the two pins showing red wire are connected together. But I have no first-hand knowledge of game gadget wiring.

Comment: The outer shield is probably connectedto ground at the other end. If that's the right pinout then the two "red" pins are connected to just one wire. I claim no responsibility if that's not actually the right pinout, by the way - double-check it! Preferably with the plug you cut off.

Comment: @RichardCrowley it is directly underneath (almost parallel) the yellow wire in the second photo.

Comment: You will have to trace that out for yourself. Please remember that the wire colors are NEVER guaranteed.  You should ALWAYS double-check to confirm they go where you think they go.  It seems reasonably clear that: White = circuit ground; Red = 3.3V power; Yellow = I2C Clock; and Green = I2C Data.  That is all you need for I2C + Power.  You might want to leave your options open and allow for connecting the spiral shield also to Ground. Only you can figure out where the other wire goes.  It may just be an extra ground wire. Especially if it is un-insulated and touching the shield wires.